# Computer not booting

Tags: motherboard

I've built a mining computer with an asrock h81 pro btc, AX 760 psu, Intel Pentium Dual Core G322 and 6* Gigabyte R9 270. I tried to boot it up without the graphics card. I plugged the screen directly into the board, and turned it on. It starts and stops a couple of times, before it runs for a while and then reboots again and repeat's it. There is nothing happening on the screen at all. what could be wrong?

Comment: Does the reboot loop occur without the screen plugged in?

Comment: yes it does :-(

Comment: The problem is then obviously occurring outside of the screen. Try disconnecting non-essential parts from the motherboard (e.g. hard drives, storage devices, and optical drives) and ensure that the power supply is sufficient.

Comment: disconnected everything, but it boots the same way. Got 2 AX 760's for the rig, so tried the other psu. The psu is not grounded, and not connected to the motherboard with metal exept for the cables.

Comment: Could it be the RAM? Using some RAM from my server from 2009.

Comment: is he having the same problem as me, or am i wrong? [link](http://www.overclock.net/t/1456912/2x-asrock-h81-pro-btc-fried-cant-be-swapped-mobo-wont-boot-help-mining-rig)

Comment: I don't think it's the same problem. There are too many variables involved in the other link for me to be sure.

Comment: I figured out that my ram was 1,9v and my motherboard was 1,5v. So i'm going to buy some new ram cards and see if it works :)